# Save and load big array (> 100 gb) python, and/or reduce size

Tags: python, file, numpy, save, h5py

I need to save a really big array (is a matrix of `double`s, with size of 5e5 x 3e4.

The context is: I have a 1D simulation of viscous disc, each row is a snapshot of the simulation ( the surface density).

all the data is relevant (more or less), so in principle i cannot reduce the size of the matrix.
I tried using `np.save` and `h5py`. with that, a matrix of `5e4x1.5e3` has a size of 6 gb in the disc. `h5py` is faster than `np.save` writing it, but I dont know if that will be the case for the full simulation (which should be something like 110 GB.
is there a way to store the data in less space? or, is there another way to save and load the data that can be faster than the other two methods?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your data dense or are zeros a possibility?

Comment: there are some zeros, but they are easily less tan 20% of the data

Comment: Well I would say sparse matrices will not help you in that case. You've said no reduction so SVD, NMF, PCA, etc go right out the window. So I really don't know how else you are going to save space. One obvious and somewhat unrelated concern would be that trying to operate on something so large your system should probably have at least that much memory.

Comment: Is float really not sufficient for your results? Is the data compressible? Do you wan't to save the snapshots directly when they are callculated, or all the data at the end of the simulation? And the most important question, how do you wan't to read your data afterwards (only subsets of a given shape?)

Comment: Floats are enough, I don't know what you mean with compressible.  I can save them directly now .  I would like to read some rows individually,  depending of what part of the simulation is relevant.  I don't need all the snapshots, but I cannot truly know a priori which one to save and which  no.  Thanks